# What is the best library in python to use to interface with a SQL database?

Tags: python, database, eclipse

I am currently processing text/html data and I wish to store my results in some sort of database. My current setup is Pydev with Eclipse.

1. What is the best non-distributed database to use with my current development environment?
2. What is the best library in python to use to interface with suggested database?

Comment: Without any detail we cannot reasonably answer this.

Comment: If your current development environment is like my current development environment, then you can use the same database I'm using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you won't be using the database itself from multiple locations at once then you can use the built-in [`sqlite3`](http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html) module with a SQLite database.

Comment: If you mean what C library then it's just libsqlite3.

Comment: You... use the built-in `sqlite3` module.

Answer (score 2):

"Best" of course depends on your needs, and aside from "text/html data" you haven't given us anything to go on.  One might say that a relational database is not the best way to store text/HTML data, but again without more info who could really say?

Given that you limited the answers to "SQL" in your title, however, I can at least suggest that the [sqlalchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/) package is quite possibly the "best" way to get to the database.

Ignacio's suggestion of using [SQLite](http://sqlite.org/) as the underlying database is also a good starting point -- and an ending point, as he hints, if an "embedded" database suffices for your needs.  If you use sqlalchemy to get to it, you can keep the SQL out of your code, and if the need arises you can trivially swap SQLite out for a more powerful solution (e.g. [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/)).